# Fedora EC2 images running out of disk space

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, fedora

I am using the official [Fedora EC2 cloud AMI](https://fedoraproject.org/en/get-fedora#clouds) for some development work. By default, the root device on these these machines is only 2GB, regardless of which instance type I use. After installing some stuff, it always runs out of space and yum starts to complain.

```
[fedora@ip-10-75-10-113 ~]$ df -ah
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs          2,0G  1,6G  382M  81% /
proc               0     0     0    - /proc
sysfs              0     0     0    - /sys
devtmpfs        1,9G     0  1,9G   0% /dev
securityfs         0     0     0    - /sys/kernel/security
selinuxfs          0     0     0    - /sys/fs/selinux
tmpfs           1,9G     0  1,9G   0% /dev/shm
devpts             0     0     0    - /dev/pts
tmpfs           1,9G  172K  1,9G   1% /run
tmpfs           1,9G     0  1,9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
```

I don't have this problem with other EC2 images, such as CentOS or Ubuntu. Is there any way I can start the AMI with a single, unpartitioned disk? Or am I somehow using it in the wrong way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create the instance, just give yourself a larger EBS volume. I think the default is 5GB (could be very wrong). Just increase it. You can always create an AMI from your current instance and launch based on the AMI with a larger EBS volume if you don't want to duplicate any work you've already done.